# Searching in a TreeMap (Java)

Tags: java, treemap

I need to do a search in a map of maps and return the keys this element belong.
I think this implementation is very slow, can you help me to optimize it?.
I need to use TreeSet and I can't use contains because they use compareTo, and equals/compareTo pair are implemented in an incompatible way and I can't change that.
(sorry my bad english)

```
Map<Key, Map<SubKey, Set<Element>>> m = new TreeSet();

public String getKeys(Element element) { 
 for(Entry<Key, Map<SubKey, Set<Element>>> e : m.entrySet()) {
  mapSubKey = e.getValue();
  for(Entry<SubKey, Set<Element>> e2 : mapSubKey.entrySet()) {
   setElements = e2.getValue();
   for(Element elem : setElements)
    if(elem.equals(element)) return "Key: " + e.getKey() + " SubKey: " + e2.getKey();
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem here is that the keys and values are backward.

Maps allow one to efficiently find a value (which would be `Key` and `SubKey`) associated with a key (`Element`, in this example).

Going backwards is slow.

There are bi-directional map implementations, like Google Collections [BiMap,](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html) that support faster access in both directions—but that would mean replacing `TreeMap`. Otherwise, maintain two maps, one for each direction.

Comment: I can only use standard Java Collections and keeping a reverse map is not an option. So I think this is the only way of doing this with those prerequisites, so I'll need to optimize in another part.
Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

if you can't use `contains`, and you're stuck using a Map of Maps, then your only real option is to iterate, as you are doing.

alternatively, you could keep a reverse map of `Element` to `Key/SubKey` in a separate map, which would make reverse lookups faster.

also, if you're not sure that a given `Element` can exist in only one place, you might want to store and retrieve a `List<Element>` instead of just an `Element`

Comment: It's a problem?/practice? for the University, and I'm stuck with prerequisites, so keeping a reverse map is not an option. 
Element only exists in one place. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: In java elements ALWAYS only exist in one place, however multiple collections can contain references to the same object.  Generally to do this kind of thing I would implement my own collection that wraps all the functionality you need--that way you may have two collections inside doing the work, but your collection is the only one users would see.  This also makes changes much easier later when they change the requirements on you.

Answer (score 1):

Using [TreeMap](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) and [TreeSet](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) work properly when [compareTo](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo(T)) and [equals](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) are implemented in such a way that they are compatible with each other. Furthermore, when searching in a Map, only the search for the key will be efficient (for a TreeMap O(log n)). When searching for a value in a Map, the complexity will become linear.

There is a way to optimize the search in the inner [TreeSet](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) though, when implementing your own [Comparator](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) for the Element type. This way you can implement your own compareTo method without changing the Element object itself.

Comment: I don't understand you, I have compareTo (Comparable) and compare (Comparator) methods implemented for Element, but they are implemented in a way incompatible with equals(this is a prerequisite), so I have to check before adding if there is an equal element in the treeset already. 
Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a bidirectional TreeMap (or Bijection over TreeMap).

It associates two overloaded TreeMaps Which are tied together.

Each one "inverse" constant field points to the other TreeMap. Any change on one TreeMap is automatically reflected on its inverse.

As a result, each value is unique.

```
public class BiTreeMap<K, V> extends TreeMap<K, V> {
    public final BiTreeMap<V, K> inverse;

    private BiTreeMap(BiTreeMap inverse) {
        this.inverse = inverse;
    }

    public BiTreeMap() {
        inverse = new BiTreeMap<V, K>(this);
    }

    public BiTreeMap(Map<? extends K, ? extends V> m) {
        inverse = new BiTreeMap<V, K>(this);
        putAll(m);
    }

    public BiTreeMap(Comparator<? super K> comparator) {
        super(comparator);
        inverse = new BiTreeMap<V, K>(this);
    }

    public BiTreeMap(Comparator<? super K> comparatorK, Comparator<? super V> comparatorV) {
        super(comparatorK);
        inverse = new BiTreeMap<V, K>(this, comparatorV);
    }

    private BiTreeMap(BiTreeMap<V, K> inverse, Comparator<? super K> comparatorK) {
        super(comparatorK);
        this.inverse = inverse;
    }

    @Override
    public V put(K key, V value) {
        if(key == null || value == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }
        V oldValue = super.put(key, value);
        if (oldValue != null && inverse._compareKeys(value, oldValue) != 0) {
            inverse._remove(oldValue);
        }
        K inverseOldKey = inverse._put(value, key);
        if (inverseOldKey != null && _compareKeys(key, inverseOldKey) != 0) {
            super.remove(inverseOldKey);
        }
        return oldValue;
    }

    private int _compareKeys(K k1, K k2) {
        Comparator<? super K> c = comparator();
        if (c == null) {
            Comparable<? super K> ck1 = (Comparable<? super K>) k1;
            return ck1.compareTo(k2);
        } else {
            return c.compare(k1, k2);
        }
    }

    private V _put(K key, V value) {
        return super.put(key, value);
    }

    @Override
    public V remove(Object key) {
        V value = super.remove(key);
        inverse._remove(value);
        return value;
    }

    private V _remove(Object key) {
        return super.remove(key);
    }

    @Override
    public void putAll(Map<? extends K, ? extends V> map) {
        for (Map.Entry<? extends K, ? extends V> e : map.entrySet()) {
            K key = e.getKey();
            V value = e.getValue();
            put(key, value);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void clear() {
        super.clear();
        inverse._clear();
    }

    private void _clear() {
        super.clear();
    }

    public boolean containsValue(Object value) {
        return inverse.containsKey(value);
    }

    @Override
    public Map.Entry<K, V> pollFirstEntry() {
        Map.Entry<K, V> entry = super.pollFirstEntry();
        inverse._remove(entry.getValue());
        return entry;
    }

    @Override
    public Map.Entry<K, V> pollLastEntry() {
        Map.Entry<K, V> entry = super.pollLastEntry();
        inverse._remove(entry.getValue());
        return entry;
    }
}
```